# Rust anonyomous static array

Tags: rust

I'm trying to initialize a struct with the following layout:

```
struct BytePattern {
    pattern: &'static [u8],
    mask: &'static [u8]
};
```

Can I initialize this inline, something like:

```
return BytePattern {
    pattern: &'static [0x00u8, 0x00u8, 0x01u8, 0x00u8],
    mask:  &'static  [0xFFu8, 0xFFu8, 0xFFu8, 0xFFu8]
}
```

Edit: The above syntax returns `error: expected  :, found '['

Edit: [Reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/2nkwts/rust_static_array_members_declared_inline/) supplied the following hack to do it (yes I'm a jerk and ask in multiple places for this language)

```
return BytePattern {
    pattern: { static P: &'static [u8] = &[0x00u8, 0x00u8, 0x01u8, 0x00u8]; P },
    mask:    { static M: &'static [u8] = &[0xFFu8, 0xFFu8, 0xFFu8, 0xFFu8]; M },
}
```

Which is...terrible, but works. I'll use it if I can't find something different

Comment: @MatthieuM. I did, I updated the question

Comment: (If you're going to cross-post questions to multiple sites, it's at least polite to provide links between them.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use byte string literals to produce a `&'static [u8]`:

```
BytePattern {
    pattern: b"\x00\x00\x01\x00",
    mask:  b"\xff\xff\xff\xff",
}
```

This of course is not a general solution for any static slices, but takes care of the `u8` case.